# Dsymutil Warning

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I met a problem, in the use of ***libCrasheye.a*** library, to display the alarm.

> while processing
>   /Users/caiqiujun/Documents/iOS/Swift/WageWebsite/WageWebsite/Framework/crasheye/libCrasheye.a(CrasheyeUnityPlugin.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/test/Documents/crashsvn910/Crasheye/DerivedData/ModuleCache/1GC1H3S0HXFE/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> note: Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static
>   libraries.

Why show the above alarm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it say

> Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static libraries.

So you have to contact the library's developer and ask to disable debugging of the library module before shipping his library.
So he as to recompile his application